What is an actual bitcoin worth "blockchain"
Blockchain bitcoin was founded in 2009 is that correct?
What about the blockchain?
Where?

Hey Luke, I’m afraid that I don’t understand what you are asking. Could you please edit your question to make sure that it is easy to understand what you want to know more about?
